# Flink migration: BucketingSink[T] to StreamingFileSink[T]

Tags: java, scala, apache-flink

I have oldest version Flink and want to update it to latest stable version. `BucketingSink` is depricated in latest version and I try to change it with `StreamingFileSink`. To init it I use `StreamingFileSink.forBulkFormat` but have the error:

```
type arguments [T] do not conform to method forSpecificRecord's type parameter bo
unds [T <: org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecordBase]
[ERROR] .forBulkFormat(new Path(s"${conf.output}/$path") , AvroWriters.forSpecificRecord[T](classOf[T]) )
```

Also I cant find how to set `bucketer:DateTimeBucketer[T], inactiveBucketThreshold, writer: Writer[T]`

Could u help me find the right way.

Old code:

```
trait Runner[T <: SpecificRecordBase] extends Serializable {
      def createHdfsSink(conf: FlinkConfig, path: String): BucketingSink[T] = {
            val bucketer = new DateTimeBucketer[T]
            val sink = new BucketingSink[T](s"${conf.output}/$path")
            sink
              .setBatchSize(toBytes(conf.batchSize))
              .setBucketer(bucketer)
              .setInactiveBucketThreshold(toMillis(conf.inactiveBucketThreshold))
              .setWriter(writer)
              .setPendingPrefix(pendingPrefix)
              .setBatchRolloverInterval(conf.fileOpenIntervalTime)
      }
```

New code with errors:

```
  def createHdfsStreamingSink[T : ClassTag](conf: FlinkConfig, path: String): StreamingFileSink[T] = {
    val sink = StreamingFileSink
      .forBulkFormat(new Path(s"${conf.output}/$path") , AvroWriters.forSpecificRecord[T](classOf[T]) )
      .build()

    // TODO:        .withOutputFileConfig()
    sink
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you should use `forReflectRecord(Class<T> type)` method instead, which will use reflection to create the schema for the type and use that schema to write the records. The custom bucket assigner is configured during `StreamingFileSink` setup and is specified via `.withBucketAssigner(BucketAssigner<IN, ID> assigner)` method call.

So, finally your `StreamingFileSink` builder will look as follows:

```scala
def createHdfsStreamingSink[T : ClassTag](conf: FlinkConfig, path: String): StreamingFileSink[T] = {
    val sink = StreamingFileSink
      .forBulkFormat(new Path(s"${conf.output}/$path") , AvroWriters.forReflectRecord[T](classOf[T]) )
      .withBucketAssigner(bucketAssigner)
      .build()
    sink
}
```